# Trouble using while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
import sys
total = 0

while True:
    try:
        num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(num, "has been added to the total")
        total += num
    except:
        print("This is not a number. Please re-enter")
        continue
    while True:
        again = input("Would you like to enter another number to add (Y or N)? ")
        if again == "Y" or "y":
            break     
        elif again == "N" or "n":
            print("The sum of the numbers is:", total)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid response. Please enter Y or N")
```

My issue is after I introduced the second while loop. It seems only to be processing the `if again == "Y" or "y":` It will break and go back to the first loop which is what I want. However it  does not process the rest of the conditions. Like if the input is "N" or anything else, it will break and ignore what I have it set to do. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having trouble with this expression:

```
        if again == "Y" or "y":
```

Order of operator precedence says it is equivalent to this expression:

```
        if (again == "Y") or ("y"):
```

The value of the 1st term doesn't much matter, since the 2nd term is not `None`, so it evaluates `True`,
so the whole boolean expression will always evaluate `True`.

What you wanted was something along the lines of:

```
        if again in {'Y', 'y'}:
```

which is testing set membership.
Remember to adjust the `'N'` expression, as well.

Or, for the higher-level problem, you might choose a different tack:

```
        if again.lower() == 'y':
```